# Getting a LAMP server secured and locked down for development

Tags: security, apache2, webserver, lamp

I'm turning my VPS into a development server which will hold development copies of all my websites, controlled by git. Of course, I installed the LAMP server so I can test them.

I've already configured Apache to server through port 8080. However I'm trying to get it to  be much more secure. The idea is to only allow certain people to view the content (based on IP or password I guess). Is there a way I can do this?

Another thing I was trying to figure out is what to `chown` and `chgrp` all the files in `/var/www` to. By default (at least in my case) everything is owner by root -- which is bad news. What's the best practise here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default` and between `<Directory /var/www/></Directory>` replace

`Order allow,deny` with `Order deny,allow` and

`allow from all` with `deny from all`.

Then you can simply add your ips with `allow from IP`. After an apache reload it should work.

See also [the official documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html).

Also per default apache runs under the user `www-data`, so a `chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www` to change the user and group should solve your root problem.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I know is using `htpasswd`. With it, you can create a database of users and passwords that will restrict the access to your website as you want. You have more info here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/htpasswd.html

Answer (score 1):

> Another thing I was trying to figure out is what to chown and chgrp all the files in /var/www 
>   to. By default (at least in my case) everything is owner by root -- which is bad news. What's the best practise here?

Add `www-data` to your `username` group and create a symlink inside `/var/www` to point to where you develop(such as `/var/www/hello -> ~/projects/hello`.

For authentication, I'd also recommend the htpasswd route.